# Implications of NP=coNP for PSPACE

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

If NP = coNP, then the Polynomial Hierarchy collapses to its first level (NP).  Intuitively, it seems to me that PSPACE should collapse down to NP as well.

As a loose heuristic argument, take the PSPACE-complete problem QSAT (which is SAT where the boolean variables can be quantified with either $\forall$ or $\exists$).  Since both $\forall$- and $\exists$-type branching can be handled by NP (if we assume NP = coNP), this problem should be in NP.

Yet in a historical sense, it seems unlikely to me that NP = coNP really implies P = PSPACE.  If that were true, complexity theorists would never have tried to prove P $\ne$ NP, since they could instead try to show the "easier" claim P $\ne$ PSPACE, which would imply NP $\ne$ coNP, which would imply P $\ne$ NP.

So what's wrong with my thinking?

Comment: The wrong part is "since both $\forall$ and $\exists$-type branching can be handled by NP": a TQBF has an *arbitrary* long alternation of quantifiers (it depends on the input size); so you cannot apply the same induction argument used to show that P=PH if NP=coNP.